# Playing list of mp3 files one by one

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have list of mp3 files and I want them to play after the other.

I have attached my code.
In between I am getting error.

```
function playAudio(){
  var au = document.getElementById('saveAudio');
  if($scope.listOfMp3.length > 0){
     $scope.mp3 = $scope.listOfMp3[0];
     au.src = $scope.mp3;
     var promise = au.play();
     if (promise !== undefined) {
        promise.then(function () {
          console.log('Succesfully played');
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log('Problem in playing');
          $scope.listOfMp3.shift();
          playAudio();
        });
     }
     au.addEventListener('ended',function(){
        $scope.listOfMp3.shift();
        playAudio();
     });
  } else {
     au.pause();
  }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes when there is an error the associated message provides clues as to the problem and its resolution. The code adds event listeners but does not remove any. Each recursion and another event listener. On each recursion there will be N event listeners invoking `playAudio`.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you should get the song end event of the song and on that event, you should pass the function to play the next song.

Comment: au.addEventListener('ended'

Comment: That is what i have done but still i am getting error.